# Expire Old Sandboxes

Tags: discussion

They were built to be temporary. I understand keeping the nth and n-1th sandboxes because people still use those. Every time I search for things on meta I get so many trash results from sandboxes it's unbelievable.

In my opinion, the benefits of being able to actually use the smart-search feature on meta outweigh the extremely rare chance that a shining gem of a challenge will be found among the below average, months old challenges.

**Delete all but the latest and second to latest sandbox.**

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why you want to *keep* old sandboxes around? What value have they to future visitors? If you have a compelling argument, make it an answer so people can vote, refine, and comment.

Comment: I suppose one reason to keep them around would be so that people could look at "failed" proposals to re-design it in their own fashion.

Answer (score 9):

I would prefer they be kept. I put quite a bit of work into some of them and while I think they need more before they're ready to post, it would be upsetting for them to disappear.

But I also don't really understand the reason for wanting to delete them. Can you do `-sandbox` or something to exclude the undesired search results?

Edit: Since I've hit 2000, I can see deleted posts now. But I still represent this position for all the sub-2000 users.

Comment: You can't filter the "Similar questions" list with -sandbox, and if you are looking for a sandbox related post (of which we have a few), you can't use -sandbox either. What's more is that 95% of the *good* material has made it *out* of the sandbox already. It's called a sandbox for a reason - you build something out of sand, and it gets washed away at some point.

Comment: I could quip back with things like "baby with the bathwater" or "long incubation", but I still don't grasp the issue fully, so it would be pointlessly argumentative. What's "Similar questions"?

Comment: When you write a question, when you suggest a duplicate, and when you search, meta uses a smart search feature to identify similar questions or search results. Not only are the sandboxes themselves showing up in mass numbers, but also every single answer ever posted to *any* of them. What's worse is that the good material from the old ones has already been *duplicated*. Are we programmers or hoarders?